# Is it good practice to catch exception, log and throw the exception again?

Tags: c#, exception

For the purpose of logging, I would like to catch an exception. But since I would also need to throw the exception, I would then throw the exception again. For example, I would do this in C# as below:

```
try
{
    //exception-prone code block here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   Logger.Log(ex);
   throw new Exception(ex);
}
```

Now I am curious is this the best way for the purpose of logging? Suggestions please.

Comment: It's worth noting that you are losing your stack trace here if you re-throw like this. Just use `throw;` instead.

Comment: Do you have a global OnError event, which could log the error for you, so you could just throw it?

Comment: this might also be a handy read here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: @DavidG, nice catch. I would resort to throw; after doing logging tasks. Thanks.

Comment: Agree with @Serv. If you know how to process an exception, catch it. If you don't know, then do not touch it, and then up-level catcher will log it.

Comment: I have given an answer, elaborating on my comment. You can use `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event in console, WinForms / WPF and the `Applicaiton_Error` in Asp.Net.

Comment: Exception handling is expensive and breaks the flow of the program, as such exception handling should only be used when there is no alternative. ie its impossible to check whether an action will succeed before preforming it or if its impossible to handle what ever has gone wrong with out user input. so all exception handling should be on the micro scale ie as small as possible. there should never be any cause for an exception handler to raise an exception, the very worst that should happen is that the exception be logged and the user informed that an error occured

Comment: @MikeT, "the exception be logged and the user informed that an error occured" - I think this is the best combination because we would like both the parties be informed with sufficient information should there happen any exception.

Comment: @MikeT, For the best, you could add an answer with the examples you would like to elaborate.

Comment: as i said that is the worst case, the idea case is that the exception occurred for some known reason like a file is locked in which case a simple retry may solve the exception in which case informing the user is pointless though logging it to highlight the issue for future prevention of the issue is always useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no best way of logging. It always depends on what you need.

But if you want to reduce code and just log the error, you could create your own event handler and attach it to a specific event.

Take the for example the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event:

Demo code from MSDN:

```
public class Example 
{
   [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags=SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlAppDomain)]
   public static void Main()
   {
      AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
      currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);

      try {
         throw new Exception("1");
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Console.WriteLine("Catch clause caught : {0} \n", e.Message);
      }

          throw new Exception("2");
       }

       static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args) 
       {
          Exception e = (Exception) args.ExceptionObject;
          Console.WriteLine("MyHandler caught : " + e.Message);
          Console.WriteLine("Runtime terminating: {0}", args.IsTerminating);
       }
    }
}
```

You could put your loggin in the MyHandler method and be done with it. You wouldn't need to abuse a catch block without really dealing with the exception.

In Asp.Net you could override the Application_Error method in the global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    logger.Fatal(ex);
}
```

Based on your logging routine, anything could be done now. In my above case, every fatal exception, gets send via email to an incident management system.

In my oppinion the keypoint is, that a `try / catch` is supposed to handle exceptions. Logging an error in a catch block is like having a no statements in a catch block at all, **you are just swallowing the exception, without handling it.** In the end it's just redundant code.

Comment: Server.GetLastError(); Could you elaborate a bit please? Last means any intermediate errors won't be caught?

Comment: Since this method is always invoked when an exceptions happens, it only needs to get the last error that has happened. It will be the most recent one. Any "intermediate" error has already been dealt with by this eventhandler.

Comment: What is `NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger` ?

Answer (score 4):

> For the purpose of logging, I would like to catch an exception

It's not a preferred option any more.

With new [C# 6.0](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#exception-filters) feature (called *Exception filters*) you have special way to log exceptions

```
private static bool Log(Exception e) { /* log it */ ; return false; }
…
try { … } catch (Exception e) when (Log(e)) {}
```

This way is recommended, as you don't have to re-throw.

Comment: Seems C# 6.0 would make it a lot easier. For now I am upto .net 4.5. Would be passionately waiting! :)

Comment: .Net version has nothing to do with C# compiler. You **can** compile for 4.5 while having exception filters at your disposal (assuming you are using latest VS 2015+).

Comment: Well, VS2015 is out. Go for it, C# 6.0 is too cool to spend even a day without it.

Comment: not always a developers choice, often there are budgetary or procedural issues preventing getting new products when they are freshly released. I'm still stuck with VS2012 for exactly those reasons

Comment: Also worth noting that using the when clause to log is an accepted abuse, not a preferred method. so basically its a hack that they know everyone will use anyway

Comment: @Sinatr: from the link you posted "It is also a common and accepted form of “abuse” to use exception filters for side effects; e.g. logging" so thats not contradicting him its paraphrasing him

Comment: What he is saying is that 'if' your handler can only handle the exception in certain circumstances then this will bypass the handler when it can't be used maintaining the call stack for when it reaches the correct handler.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is more about best Practice for Error Handling than best practice for logging exceptions

Exception handling is an expensive process that deliberately breaks the correct flow of your program, so should not be used as your default checking mechanism, that should always be validation checks.for example if you want to create a file, check if the file exists before creating it, this then allows the normal flow of the program to handle expected situations.

exception handling should only be used as the name suggests in exceptional circumstances. either when the exception is something not expected or its impossible for you to decide how to handle the exception with out further information.
for example in the above the MS framework gives you a function to check if a file exists, but if the file creation is called and the file is already there what should it do? Append to the Existing file? delete it and create a new one?? try again with a different filename? Microsoft can't know what is the correct way to handle this so have to raise an exception to let you know that you did something you shouldn't have. as such this is the only time you should raise an exception in your code.

if you're a handling an exception then that is exactly what you should do, handle it you should never need to throw an exception inside an exception handler unless you are developing class libraries in which case is isn't appropriate for a library to communicate with the user, in which case the exceptions should be left unhandled or rethrown with additional information. if you can't handle an exception at the point you are in the code then your exception handler is in the wrong place.

an exception handler should do 1 of 3 things

1. perform a predefine action that corrects an error
       ie wait 5 seconds and try again
2. ask the user which predefine action is the correct way to solve the error 
       ie Retry or Cancel
3. report the error to the user and return the program to a stable
   state
       ie Could not save file at this time because blah blah, try again later

any one of these action can include logging of the exception, but all of them should be final

```
try
{
    //exception-prone code block here
}
catch(KnowException1 ex)
{
   Logger.Log(ex); //logging may be optional as its a known handled situation
   //perform predefined action
}
catch(KnowException2 ex)
{
   Logger.Log(ex); //logging may be optional as its a known handled situation
   // fire message box asking users how to proceed
   //perform selected predefined action
}
catch(UnknowException ex)
{
   Logger.Log(ex); //logging is vital
   // fire message box something unexpected happened
   //cancel action and return to normal operations
}
```

this is why its always advisable to raise an appropriately typed exception

Comment: Nice points on the tasks exception handler should do. I agree it would be best practice to code in the way it would generate as minimum exceptions as possible.

Comment: What is `Logger.Log` ?

Comment: been a while but i would say the log function of a centralised logger class, that will contain the logging methodology, ie log to central error DB, application event logs, web service logs, text file or anything else that is used as a log

Answer (score 1):

Defining and maintaining a custom exception store would enhance the support experience and make the lives of the maintenance engineers much easier.

**Please refer MSDN's Strongly recommended guidelines for Custom Exceptions.**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229064(v=vs.100).aspx

For example, assume that you are selling a killer home appliance with your software onboard. Having your custom exception would make it easier for a maintenance personnel to understand what's wrong with your device and save some precious debugging time.

Comment: agreed. To have detailed logger in catch block in any exception prone code would serve the purpose you are referring to. :) Will look into the guidelines you pointed. Thank you.